# Dynamodb 'orter by' based on a hash and other column criteria

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I'm using dynamo db, I was reading this document [Class QueryRequest](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/model/QueryRequest.html) and says literately:

> You can narrow the scope of the query by using comparison operators on
>   the range key value, or on the index key. You can use the
>   ScanIndexForward parameter to get results in forward or reverse order,
>   by range key or by index key.

But, I need know if is possible to sort my data according to another parameter (different to hash or range).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only Query a Table of type Hash and Range, or a Local Secondary Index or a Global Secondary Index. You have to create the Table with the indexes, so if you haven't then you cannot query on them.